# Setting the Firebase user.uid to a global variable

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the `user.id` of a user after successful login using Angular/Firebase then assign it into a global variable. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to build a service to manage your users. A service is a singleton so it's a proper way to store and manage these types of data.

You can build something like this:

```
    //... code of your service ..

    Var currentUser={};

        function login()
        {    
                // ... Code of you login function including you auth method ...
                if (user && !user.isAnonymous) {
                       currentUser.userid = user.uid;
                } 
        }

        function getCurrentUser(){
           return currentUser;
        }
```

Comment: thanks for response sir but i'm actually really new to angular and i don't know much about services just yet . What i simply want to do here is to be able to get the user id of the currently authenticated user without the need to call -firebase.onAuthStatechange- function again and again everytime i try to put data on my realtime database .

Comment: I've just add something in my example. In fact you can easily get you currentUser with a type of getter without call -firebase.onAuthStatechange-. You just need to build a correct login fonction that initialize your currentUser.